# Why is my button addon way bigger than my text input?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used an input group straight from the bootstrap documentation, and for some reason the button is way bigger than the text input.

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input ng-model="businessName" ng-model="chosenPlace" googleplace type="text" class="form-control input-lg">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button ng-click="findGPlace2()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Find!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't made any changes to the css, just vanilla bootstrap.

Comment: @davidkonrad I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: Use input-group-lg on the input-group and remove the input-lg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the samples in Boostrap page. [This](http://www.bootply.com/0OSNeMcNyv) is the bootply link you can customize it.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="input-group">
      <input ng-model="businessName" ng-model="chosenPlace" class="form-control input-lg">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button ng-click="findGPlace2()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button">Find!</button>
              </span>
          </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 exactly, you came first :) here is a 3..1x fiddle with the same -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wDsk/2/

Comment: @davidkonrad and master994 thanks a ton! I pasted in your fiddles line for line, and still am getting the large button. I swear I'm not a dunce, but this is just weird and I can't seem to figure it out. See screenshot: http://monosnap.com/image/YwcaaYU3ScjUeZdxXyK1pXczQ03aTT

Comment: @novicePrgrmr, reset your cache or press F5 multiple times

Comment: Cache problem occured i think. After that please take a pic about the developer tools which classes and css stuff on the input.

Comment: I reset my cache and still it's huge. Here is snapshot of the Google Dev Tools http://monosnap.com/image/sIM5wSQnJghsLigfA9nRBONIJRVztI

Comment: Need to see what property or class cause the problem. Need all list of classes from dev tools. It have to be some custom css...

Comment: @novicePrgrmr Can you make a fiddle reproducing the behaviour?

Comment: @novicePrgmr since the example above works fine as a standalone there must be an error somewhere in your HTML or custom CSS. My hunch is that you are missing a tag somewhere in your HTML. I suggest giving us more (or all) of the HTML file that contains this form.